# What am I supposed to do to find the root directory of Apache/2.4.6 on Centos7 (or other systems)?

Tags: apache, centos7, httpd.conf

I successfully used `yum install httpd` to install apahche server, and used `httpd -k start` directive to start the server. But I don't know where the root directory of httpd (as well as the httpd.conf) is located. It's said that the root directory varies depending on systems, but is there any convinient and general way to find it?

Comment: `httpd -t -D DUMP_RUN_CFG` is probably a good starting point but I don't know how cross-platform it is.

Comment: That's great! It works on centos 7, very clear. Thx for the comment!